# CSS Grid, FlexBox - how to keep containers from overlapping?

Tags: html, jquery, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a web page that draws cards and displays text. The text and images overlap.

I can't figure out how to make them not overlap with FlexBox, grid CSS.

```js
var obj;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = "https://clearlightdoor.com/s3cards";
  $("#save_file").css("visibility", "hidden");

  // Use $.ajax instead of $.getJSON to handle asynchronous loading
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      obj = data['AllData'];
      
      for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#tenth-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 1) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#nineth-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 2) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#eighth-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 3) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#seventh-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 4) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#sixth-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 5) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#fifth-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 6) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#fourth-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 7) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#third-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 9) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#first-card").prepend(td_data);
        }
      }
    }
  });

  var inc = 10;

  $("#next_btn").click(function() {
    inc = inc - 1;

    if (inc == 9) {
      $("#first-card").css("visibility", "visible");
      $("#start_text").remove();
      var first_text = obj[9]["line"];
      $("#card_text").append(first_text);
    } else if (inc == 8) {
     // $("#second-card").css("visibility", "visible");
      var second_data = obj[8]["img"];
      $("#first-card").append(second_data);
      $("#card_text").text("");
      $("#card_text").append(obj[inc]["line"]);
    } else if (inc == 7) {
      $("#third-card").css("visibility", "visible");
      $("#card_text").text("");
      $("#card_text").append(obj[inc]["line"]);      
    } else if (inc == 6) {
      $("#fourth-card").css("visibility", "visible");
      $("#card_text").text("");
      $("#card_text").append(obj[inc]["line"]);      
    } else if (inc == 5) {
      $("#fifth-card").css("visibility", "visible");
      $("#card_text").text("");
      $("#card_text").append(obj[inc]["line"]);      
    } else if (inc == 4) {
      $("#sixth-card").css("visibility", "visible");
    } else if (inc == 3) {
      $("#seventh-card").css("visibility", "visible");
    } else if (inc == 2) {
      $("#eighth-card").css("visibility", "visible");
    } else if (inc == 1) {
      $("#nineth-card").css("visibility", "visible");
    } else if (inc == 0) {
      $("#tenth-card").css("visibility", "visible");
      $("#save_file").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
  });
});

$("#save_file").click(function() {
  var html_save = "<html><body><table>";
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    html_save += "<tr style='height: 215px;'><td valign='top'>" + obj[i]["line"] + "</td><td>" + obj[i]["img"] + "</td></tr>";
  }
  html_save += "</table></body></html>";

  var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
  hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(html_save);
  hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
  hiddenElement.download = 'tarot_reading.html';
  hiddenElement.click();
});
```

```css
/* this page uses CSS grid and FlexBox to control layout */
    body {
      font-family: 'Old Standard TT', serif;
      background-color: #1c1c1c;
      color: #d4af37;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      background-image: url("https://tarotcardsstyles.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/pattern8-pattern53b.jpg");
      background-repeat: repeat;
    }
    #card, #absolute {
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      border: 2px solid #d4af37;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
    a {
      color: #d4af37;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover, a:active {
      color: #fff;
    }
    a:visited {
      color: #d4af37;
    }
    .button {
      color: #d4af37;
      font-family: 'Old Standard TT', serif;
      text-decoration: none;
      border: 2px solid #d4af37;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      border-radius: 5px;
    } /* the rotate id is on the image which comes from the json. generate_ai_tarot_reading.py makes the json. */
    #rotate { 
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      border: 2px solid #d4af37;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      transform: rotate(270deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      z-index: 1;
      position: relative;
      left: -120px;
    }
    button {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #d4af37;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      padding: 7px 14px;
      border: 2px solid #d4af37;
      border-radius: 5px;
      font-family: 'Old Standard TT', serif;
      font-size: 1em;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .content-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    .start-text {
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .grid-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-top: 200px;
    }
    .grid-item {
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .card-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .card-grid {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      gap: 20px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .text-container {
      margin-top: 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .reading-grid {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      gap: 10px;
    }
    .button-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    #card_text {
      top: 400%;
      left: 100%;
      display: flex;
    }
    #first-card {
      position: relative;
    }
    #second-card, #third-card, #fourth-card, #fifth-card, #sixth-card,
    #seventh-card, #eighth-card, #nineth-card, #tenth-card {
      position: absolute;
      visibility: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    #second-card {
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
    }
    #third-card {
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      display: flex;
    }
    #fourth-card {
      top: 0;
      left: -100%;
    }
    #fifth-card {
      top: -100%;
      left: 0;
    }
    #sixth-card {
      top: 0;
      left: 100%;
    }
    #seventh-card {
      top: 200%;
      left: 300%;
    }
    #eighth-card {
      top: 100%;
      left: 300%;
    }
    #nineth-card {
      top: 0;
      left: 300%;
    }
    #tenth-card {
      top: -100%;
      left: 300%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-container">
    <button id="next_btn" style="border:1px solid black;">Next</button>
    <br>
    <button id="save_file" style="visibility:collapse; border:1px solid black;">Save reading to file</button>
  </div>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div id="start_text" class="start-text">Think about a question you have or a situation you would like to know more about or just let yourself go still inside for a moment and click Next to begin and draw cards.</div>
    
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="card-grid">
          <div id="first-card" style="visibility: collapse">
            <div id="second-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
            <div id="third-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
            <div id="fourth-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
            <div id="fifth-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
            <div id="sixth-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
            <div id="seventh-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
            <div id="eighth-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
            <div id="nineth-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
            <div id="tenth-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div id="card_text"></div>
  </div>
```

`<div id="card_text"></div>` is the text div that is overlapping with the images.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Tarot Card game featuring Celtic cross spread. The game text was partially generated by claude-3-opus-20240229">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>The Clear Light Door</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://tarotcardsstyles.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/favicon.ico">
  <style>
  /* this page uses CSS grid and FlexBox to control layout */
    body {
      font-family: 'Old Standard TT', serif;
      background-color: #1c1c1c;
      color: #d4af37;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      background-image: url("https://tarotcardsstyles.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/pattern8-pattern53b.jpg");
      background-repeat: repeat;
    }
    #card, #absolute {
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      border: 2px solid #d4af37;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
    a {
      color: #d4af37;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover, a:active {
      color: #fff;
    }
    a:visited {
      color: #d4af37;
    }
    .button {
      color: #d4af37;
      font-family: 'Old Standard TT', serif;
      text-decoration: none;
      border: 2px solid #d4af37;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      border-radius: 5px;
    } /* the rotate id is on the image which comes from the json. generate_ai_tarot_reading.py makes the json. */
    #rotate { 
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      border: 2px solid #d4af37;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      transform: rotate(270deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      z-index: 1;
      position: relative;
      left: -120px;
    }
    button {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #d4af37;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      padding: 7px 14px;
      border: 2px solid #d4af37;
      border-radius: 5px;
      font-family: 'Old Standard TT', serif;
      font-size: 1em;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .content-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    .start-text {
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .grid-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-top: 200px;
    }
    .grid-item {
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .card-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .card-grid {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      gap: 20px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .text-container {
      margin-top: 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .reading-grid {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      gap: 10px;
    }
    .button-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    #card_text {
      top: 400%;
      left: 100%;
      display: flex;
    }
    #first-card {
      position: relative;
    }
    #second-card, #third-card, #fourth-card, #fifth-card, #sixth-card,
    #seventh-card, #eighth-card, #nineth-card, #tenth-card {
      position: absolute;
      visibility: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    #second-card {
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
    }
    #third-card {
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      display: flex;
    }
    #fourth-card {
      top: 0;
      left: -100%;
    }
    #fifth-card {
      top: -100%;
      left: 0;
    }
    #sixth-card {
      top: 0;
      left: 100%;
    }
    #seventh-card {
      top: 200%;
      left: 300%;
    }
    #eighth-card {
      top: 100%;
      left: 300%;
    }
    #nineth-card {
      top: 0;
      left: 300%;
    }
    #tenth-card {
      top: -100%;
      left: 300%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="button-container">
    <button id="next_btn" style="border:1px solid black;">Next</button>
    <br>
    <button id="save_file" style="visibility:collapse; border:1px solid black;">Save reading to file</button>
  </div>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div id="start_text" class="start-text">Think about a question you have or a situation you would like to know more about or just let yourself go still inside for a moment and click Next to begin and draw cards.</div>
    
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="card-grid">
          <div id="first-card" style="visibility: collapse">
            <div id="second-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
            <div id="third-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
            <div id="fourth-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
            <div id="fifth-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
            <div id="sixth-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
            <div id="seventh-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
            <div id="eighth-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
            <div id="nineth-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
            <div id="tenth-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div id="card_text"></div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
/*global $*/
var obj;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = "https://clearlightdoor.com/s3cards";
  $("#save_file").css("visibility", "hidden");

  // Use $.ajax instead of $.getJSON to handle asynchronous loading
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      obj = data['AllData'];
      
      for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#tenth-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 1) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#nineth-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 2) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#eighth-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 3) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#seventh-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 4) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#sixth-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 5) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#fifth-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 6) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#fourth-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 7) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#third-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 9) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#first-card").prepend(td_data);
        }
      }
    }
  });

  var inc = 10;

  $("#next_btn").click(function() {
    inc = inc - 1;

    if (inc == 9) {
      $("#first-card").css("visibility", "visible");
      $("#start_text").remove();
      var first_text = obj[9]["line"];
      $("#card_text").append(first_text);
    } else if (inc == 8) {
     // $("#second-card").css("visibility", "visible");
      var second_data = obj[8]["img"];
      $("#first-card").append(second_data);
      $("#card_text").text("");
      $("#card_text").append(obj[inc]["line"]);
    } else if (inc == 7) {
      $("#third-card").css("visibility", "visible");
      $("#card_text").text("");
      $("#card_text").append(obj[inc]["line"]);      
    } else if (inc == 6) {
      $("#fourth-card").css("visibility", "visible");
      $("#card_text").text("");
      $("#card_text").append(obj[inc]["line"]);      
    } else if (inc == 5) {
      $("#fifth-card").css("visibility", "visible");
      $("#card_text").text("");
      $("#card_text").append(obj[inc]["line"]);      
    } else if (inc == 4) {
      $("#sixth-card").css("visibility", "visible");
    } else if (inc == 3) {
      $("#seventh-card").css("visibility", "visible");
    } else if (inc == 2) {
      $("#eighth-card").css("visibility", "visible");
    } else if (inc == 1) {
      $("#nineth-card").css("visibility", "visible");
    } else if (inc == 0) {
      $("#tenth-card").css("visibility", "visible");
      $("#save_file").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
  });
});

$("#save_file").click(function() {
  var html_save = "<html><body><table>";
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    html_save += "<tr style='height: 215px;'><td valign='top'>" + obj[i]["line"] + "</td><td>" + obj[i]["img"] + "</td></tr>";
  }
  html_save += "</table></body></html>";

  var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
  hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(html_save);
  hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
  hiddenElement.download = 'tarot_reading.html';
  hiddenElement.click();
});      
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Is js necessary for your example? What card images are you trying to avoid the text to overlap? Can you edit the snippet to contain only code relevant to your question?

Comment: <div id="third-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div> and the card_text overlap.

Comment: Is there any text in your card_text element? The only text I see isn't overlapping any cards. Please delete everything except the minimum that shows your problem. For example only one card and text that is overlapping it.

Comment: The text gets loaded into the card_text container. It runs locally if I leave it whole. The css and html are chopped up in the edit you made for me. I think the relevant parts are there. Idk how to bound the area that is at issue within that html.

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm dynamically modifying the DOM, I can't keep things apart strictly by rule. I ended up using margin padding to get things like I need them to be.
It doesn't render properly currently on a mobile device. The second card isn't crossing the first but floating off to the left. So, still some work to do, but the answer may not be as simple as a switch to prevent overlapping.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Tarot Card game featuring Celtic cross spread. The game text was partially generated by claude-3-opus-20240229">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>The Clear Light Door</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://tarotcardsstyles.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/favicon.ico">
  <style>
  /* this page uses CSS grid and FlexBox to control layout */
    body {
      font-family: 'Old Standard TT', serif;
      background-color: #1c1c1c;
      color: #d4af37;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      background-image: url("https://tarotcardsstyles.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/pattern8-pattern53b.jpg");
      background-repeat: repeat;
    }
    #card, #absolute {
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      border: 2px solid #d4af37;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
    a {
      color: #d4af37;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover, a:active {
      color: #fff;
    }
    a:visited {
      color: #d4af37;
    }
    .button {
      color: #d4af37;
      font-family: 'Old Standard TT', serif;
      text-decoration: none;
      border: 2px solid #d4af37;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      border-radius: 5px;
    } /* the rotate id is on the image which comes from the json. generate_ai_tarot_reading.py makes the json. */
    #rotate { 
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      border: 2px solid #d4af37;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      transform: rotate(270deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      z-index: 1;
      position: relative;
      left: -120px;
    }
    button {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #d4af37;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      padding: 7px 14px;
      border: 2px solid #d4af37;
      border-radius: 5px;
      font-family: 'Old Standard TT', serif;
      font-size: 1em;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .content-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .top-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      align-items: flex-start;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    .cardtext-container {
      margin-right: 40px;
      text-align: left;
      max-width: 300px;
      padding-left: 20px;
    }
    
    .grid-container {
      margin-top: 0;
      padding-left: 40px;
      border-left: 2px solid #d4af37;
    }
    
    .card-grid {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      gap: 20px;
      position: relative;
      margin-bottom: 350px;
      margin-left: 60px; /* Add this line */
    }
    .button-container {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .start-text {
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .grid-item {
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .card-container {
      display: flex;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .card-grid {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      gap: 20px;
      position: relative;
      margin-bottom: 350px;
      margin-left: 350px;
      margin-top: 150px;
    }
    
    .text-container {
      margin-top: 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .reading-grid {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      gap: 10px;
    }

    #first-card {
      position: relative;
    }
    #second-card, #third-card, #fourth-card, #fifth-card, #sixth-card,
    #seventh-card, #eighth-card, #nineth-card, #tenth-card {
      position: absolute;
      visibility: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    #second-card {
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
    }
    #third-card {
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      display: flex;
    }
    #fourth-card {
      top: 0;
      left: -100%;
    }
    #fifth-card {
      top: -100%;
      left: 0;
    }
    #sixth-card {
      top: 0;
      left: 100%;
    }
    #seventh-card {
      top: 200%;
      left: 300%;
    }
    #eighth-card {
      top: 100%;
      left: 300%;
    }
    #nineth-card {
      top: 0;
      left: 300%;
    }
    #tenth-card {
      top: -100%;
      left: 300%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="button-container">
    <button id="next_btn" style="border:1px solid black;">Next</button>
    <br>
    <button id="save_file" style="visibility:collapse; border:1px solid black;">Save reading to file</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="top-container">
      <div class="cardtext-container">
        <div id="card_text"></div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-item">
          <div class="card-grid">
            <div id="first-card" style="visibility: collapse">
              <div id="second-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
              <div id="third-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
              <div id="fourth-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
              <div id="fifth-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
              <div id="sixth-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
              <div id="seventh-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
              <div id="eighth-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
              <div id="nineth-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
              <div id="tenth-card" style="visibility: collapse"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="start_text" class="start-text">Think about a question you have or a situation you would like to know more about or just let yourself go still inside for a moment and click Next to begin and draw cards.</div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
/*global $*/
var obj;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = "https://clearlightdoor.com/s3cards";
  $("#save_file").css("visibility", "hidden");

  // Use $.ajax instead of $.getJSON to handle asynchronous loading
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      obj = data['AllData'];
      
      for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#tenth-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 1) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#nineth-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 2) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#eighth-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 3) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#seventh-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 4) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#sixth-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 5) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#fifth-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 6) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#fourth-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 7) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#third-card").append(td_data);
        } else if (i == 9) {
          var td_data = obj[i]["img"];
          $("#first-card").prepend(td_data);
        }
      }
    }
  });

  var inc = 10;

  $("#next_btn").click(function() {
    inc = inc - 1;

    if (inc == 9) {
      $("#first-card").css("visibility", "visible");
      $("#start_text").remove();
      var first_text = obj[9]["line"];
      $("#card_text").append(first_text);
    } else if (inc == 8) {
     // $("#second-card").css("visibility", "visible");
      var second_data = obj[8]["img"];
      $("#first-card").append(second_data);
      $("#card_text").text("");
      $("#card_text").append(obj[inc]["line"]);
    } else if (inc == 7) {
      $("#third-card").css("visibility", "visible");
      $("#card_text").text("");
      $("#card_text").append(obj[inc]["line"]);      
    } else if (inc == 6) {
      $("#fourth-card").css("visibility", "visible");
      $("#card_text").text("");
      $("#card_text").append(obj[inc]["line"]);      
    } else if (inc == 5) {
      $("#fifth-card").css("visibility", "visible");
      $("#card_text").text("");
      $("#card_text").append(obj[inc]["line"]);      
    } else if (inc == 4) {
      $("#sixth-card").css("visibility", "visible");
      $("#card_text").text("");
      $("#card_text").append(obj[inc]["line"]);         
    } else if (inc == 3) {
      $("#seventh-card").css("visibility", "visible");
      $("#card_text").text("");
      $("#card_text").append(obj[inc]["line"]);         
    } else if (inc == 2) {
      $("#eighth-card").css("visibility", "visible");
      $("#card_text").text("");
      $("#card_text").append(obj[inc]["line"]);         
    } else if (inc == 1) {
      $("#nineth-card").css("visibility", "visible");
      $("#card_text").text("");
      $("#card_text").append(obj[inc]["line"]);         
    } else if (inc == 0) {
      $("#tenth-card").css("visibility", "visible");
      $("#card_text").text("");
      $("#card_text").append(obj[inc]["line"]);         
      $("#save_file").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
  });
});

$("#save_file").click(function() {
  var html_save = "<html><body><table>";
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    html_save += "<tr style='height: 215px;'><td valign='top'>" + obj[i]["line"] + "</td><td>" + obj[i]["img"] + "</td></tr>";
  }
  html_save += "</table></body></html>";

  var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
  hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(html_save);
  hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
  hiddenElement.download = 'tarot_reading.html';
  hiddenElement.click();
});      
</script>
</html>
```